# RMI registry filter rejects Rmi Configuration class in java 8 update 121

Tags: java, security, rmi

Java 8 update 121 adds in part filters for deserialization, RMI registry serial filter and RMI DGC Serail filter, see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u121-relnotes-3315208.html).

Presently I'm trying to unmarshall a class used for Rmi configuration which we've made. Without any system property the filter does not allow it and using the system property `-Dsun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=<package_name>.**` it still rejects the class. The log message is:

```
INFO: ObjectInputFilter REJECTED: class <package_name and class name>,     arraylength: -1, nRefs: 11, depth: 4, bytes: 837, ex: n/a
```

Debugging it is problematic as I'm looking code which does not have the source code supplied by Oracle. I can see that the check was done but am unable to see what the filter for the classes is and what the thresholds are for:

```
maxdepth=value - the maximum depth of a graph
maxrefs=value  - the maximum number of internal references
maxbytes=value - the maximum number of bytes in the input stream
maxarray=value - the maximum array length allowed
```

Is there any other way I can apply this whitelist correctly?

Comment: I guess that you might be victim of shell's wildcard globing. Did you tried `-Dsun.rmi.registry.registryFilter="<package_name>.**"` ?

Comment: Not yet. I'll give that a go.

Comment: And no luck. Still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

We are running an RMI server as well.
I solved the problem in code and not on the commandline, but both ways should work, I would guess the shell globbing was in your way.

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter", "java.**;<our package base>.**")
```

The defaults (if you don't specify a filter prop) are in the Sources of RMIRegistryImpl:
[RMIRegistryImpl.registryFilter()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5534221c23fc/src/share/classes/sun/rmi/registry/RegistryImpl.java#l388)
This allows only subclasses of 9 basic Java classes+primitives to be registered in RMI. But the whole serializable object graph behind the registered object is checked with this filter. The array limit is 10000, the max tree depth is 5.

If one tries to register a filter without naming a class white list (like "maxdepth=10000000") then the default white list of classes is still applied.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error add the following arguments in setDomainEnv.sh

```
-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterMode=combine
-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterScope=weblogic
-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter=maxDepth=10000
```

This will overwrite maxdepth defined to be 100 by default in weblogic.oif.code

Comment: It's maxdepth, not maxDepth, so the parameters should be
`-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterMode=combine
-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterScope=weblogic
-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter=maxdepth=10000`